# Cannot invoke 'CGRect.Type.init' with an argument list of type '(x: Int, y: Int, width: Float, height: Float)'

Tags: swift

I'm learning swift，but a mistake was encountered when initializing collectionview,the error message is 'Cannot invoke 'CGRect.Type.init' with an argument list of type '(x: Int, y: Int, width: Float, height: Float)''.And,here is my screenshot：

Thank you for any help！

Comment: I don't know why the picture upload failed，here is my code：
let kScreenWidth: Float  = Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
let kScreenHeight: Float = Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
let collectionView = UICollectionView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width:kScreenWidth, height: kScreenHeight), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on writing a good question and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGRect.init` has three different versions, for the three types of arguments it accepts - Int, Double, and CGFloat. Whatever values you're passing into `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` must be the same type. To fix this you might try casting your values to `Double` by wrapping them in `Double()`.

---

Regarding your comment, there's no version of `CGRect.init()` that takes `Float` parameters. Cast your `Float`s to `Double` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have passing arguments data with the different type. Here you have set x and y position with Int Type and width & height with Float data type. these all four type must be same.